# Namespace as variable for document being processed with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces

Problem is as follows, we need to transform XML files, our customer sends us 4 different files, each with different name and each file has a unique namespace, however the elements within the document are the same.

Files are named; Supplier_Invoices_1, Supplier_Invoices_2, Supplier_Invoices_3 etc. without extension, but they are XML.

The namespace for for Supplier_Invoices_2 is:

```
xmlns:wd="urn:com.cust.report/Supplier_Invoices_2"
```

For Invoice_1:

```
"urn:com.cust.report/Supplier_Invoices_1"
```

Invoice_3:

```
"urn:com.cust.report/Supplier_Invoices_3"
```

etc, etc..

Input - Example of Supplier_Invoices_2:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.cust.report/Supplier_Invoices_2">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:CF_LRV_Journal_line_group>
            <wd:Invoice_Number>SI-00026584</wd:Invoice_Number>
            <wd:Supplier_s_Invoice_Number>19031275</wd:Supplier_s_Invoice_Number>
            <wd:Invoice_Date>2019-03-18-07:00</wd:Invoice_Date>
            <wd:Supplier wd:Descriptor="Company X">
                <wd:ID wd:type="WID">d4e89886417501a66aadebf4570da733</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Supplier_Reference_ID">SUP924</wd:ID>
                <wd:ID wd:type="Supplier_ID">S-00000461</wd:ID>
            </wd:Supplier>
            <wd:Transaction_Debit_minus_Credit>1956.92</wd:Transaction_Debit_minus_Credit>          
        </wd:CF_LRV_Journal_line_group>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:wd="urn:com.cust.report/Supplier_Invoices_2">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
     <xsl:param name="XSLPath" select="base-uri()"/>
        <message>
            <data>
                <xsl:for-each select="/wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:CF_LRV_Journal_line_group" >
                    <Documents>
                        <row>
                            <path>
                                <xsl:value-of select="tokenize($XSLPath,'/')[last()]" />
                            </path>
                            <CardCode>
                                <xsl:value-of select="./wd:Supplier/wd:ID[@wd:type='Supplier_ID']"/>
                            </CardCode>
                        </row>
                    </Documents>
                    <Document_Lines>
                        <row>
                            <Price>
                                <xsl:value-of select="./wd:Transaction_Debit_minus_Credit" />
                            </Price>
                        </row>
                    </Document_Lines>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </data>
        </message>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns:wd="urn:com.cust.report/Supplier_Invoices_2">
   <data>
      <Documents>
         <row>
            <path>Supplier_Invoices_2</path>
            <CardCode>S-00000461</CardCode>
         </row>
      </Documents>
      <Document_Lines>
         <row>
            <Price>1956.92</Price>
         </row>
      </Document_Lines>
   </data>
</message>
```

My question, how can I set the namespace in my XSL document to be variable for the document it is processing?

I added xsl:param to my XSL. The top document top 5 lines look like so:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:wd="urn:com.cust.report/$npath" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
     <xsl:param name="XSLPath" select="base-uri()"/>
     <xsl:param name="npath" select="tokenize($XSLPath,'/')[last()]" />
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<message xmlns:wd="urn:com.cust.report/$npath">
   <data/>
</message>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT/XPath 2 and later you can use a namespace wildcard `*:foo` to select elements with local name `foo` in any namespace so if you use e.g. `*:Report_Data` instead of `wd:Report_Data` you should be able to process documents of the same structure but with different namespaces just fine.

As an alternative, you can use stylesheets in a chain where you normalize the namespace for the inputs in different namespaces to a common one so that you then use the common namespace in your second stylesheet.

Comment: Hi Martin,
Thanks for the quick reply.

I'd prefer to go for the first option, if I understand correctly, I can remove namespace: `xmlns:wd="urn:com.cust.report/Supplier_Invoices_2"` then find/replace all `wd:` with `*`

Comment: Ok, this works.
`<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  >
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">        
     <xsl:param name="XSLPath" select="base-uri()"/>
        <message>
            <data>
                <xsl:for-each select="/*:Report_Data/*:Report_Entry/*:CF_LRV_Journal_line_group" > ... etc`

Thanks very much.